# Regex matchig one character in no particular order

Tags: regex, powershell-4.0

I want this regex-condition to be true:

1. String is exclusively 1 or 2 characters long
2. Condition is only true when string contains 'a' or 'ab' or 'ba' or 'b'

thanks

ps: doesn't work:

1. '^[ab]{1,2}$'
2. '^[^ab]*[ab][^ab]*$'
3. '^[^ab]*([ab]{1,2})[^ab]*$'

Comment: What about `^(a|ab|ba|b)$` ?

Comment: ```ab``` probably is just a placeholder I guess? Will there be more permutations than the four you mentioned? If not just go with what @Lynn suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression with a non-capturing group might also work:

```
^(?:ab?|ba?)$
```

or with a capturing group:

```
^(ab?|ba?)$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Dha2S/1/)

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3Dha2S/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/3Dha2S/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: @Jomme ?: is non-capturing group

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pattern you enumerated: `'a' or 'ab' or 'ba' or 'b'`

```
^(?:a|ab|ba|b)$
```